# Script in /etc/init.d won't run on startup (Ubuntu 8.10)

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, init.d

I'm on Ubuntu 8.10

The script runs when called from the command line with `sudo /etc/init.d/xbindkeys start`. Here's how it looks:

```
#! /bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
case "$1" in
  start)
    xbindkeys
  ;;
  stop)
    ps aux | grep xbindkeys | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
  ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
  ;;
esac
```

I had run `sudo update-rc.d xbindkeys defaults` earlier to create the symlinks. To make sure it was linked correctly, I tried `chkconfig | grep xbindkeys`, which returns:

```
xbindkeys                        2345
```

However, after restarting, I don't see the process with `ps aux | grep xbindkeys`.

Ideas?

Comment: What do you see in the init script output when the system is starting up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xbindkeys` needs a running X server to work which isn't available at that stage of starting your system. You should add `xbindkeys` to your `.xinitrc` (see man page `xinit(1)`) or `.Xsession` (see man page `Xsession(5)`) instead.